# Simple JavaScript query selector not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this script to have a method named "call" which acts as secretary to `document.querySelectorAll()`. Example:

```
var obj = {
    call: function( s ) { return document.querySelectorAll( s ); }
};

obj.call(".test").innerHTML == "Changed";
```

---

```
<p class="test">Original</p>
```

So, obviously, (I would think) this would change the innerHTML value from "Original" to "Changed", but is not working.

I have tried other tests such as `.style.background = "red";` but that has not worked either.

I didn't see any errors in Chrome's error console so I can't figure out why this isn't working. I am a complete noob when it comes to javascript, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Call is a reserved word in javascript, probably not a good idea to try and change it

Comment: Oh really? I did not know that. Usually in Notepad++ all reserved words are in dark blue and italicized. Hmm, I'll try something else...

Comment: Using JQuery : http://jsfiddle.net/FnmxX/1/

Comment: Okay, so I changed `call` to `query`, and it still doesn't work. However, it is now showing an error message. It's saying "Cannot set background property of null."

Comment: Is the == intentional, or are you trying to assign a new HTML?

Comment: @sdespont Yeah... well no kidding. I don't wish to use jQuery. Not because I don't like it (I use it ALL the time), but I'm trying to do the dirty work since I am just now learning javascript. I don't want any gimmes.

Comment: @MikeRobinson the `==` doesn't really matter to me. I'll go try `=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QSA returns a NodeList (basically looks and acts like an array), docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

As such, you would need to compare:

`var isFoo = obj.call('.test')[0].innerHTML == 'foo';`

Some other points:

1) call is a reserved word in JS, better off picking something else

2) Are you trying to compare the result (what you're currently doing) or are you trying to set the innerHTML? If it's the latter, the code should read:

`obj.call('.test')[0].innerHTML = 'foo';`

Because == is a comparison operator, not assignment.

Comment: Okay, I did what you said. And I changed `call` to `query`, but it still isn't working. I also changed `==` to `=`, because good point, I'm assigning not comparing. I just don't know why this isn't working. ":~\

Comment: What??? It does work in the fiddle... But it doesn't work on an HTML file in a browser. (Tested in Chrome 23, IE 9, Firefox 16, Safari 5). I'll try mucking around a little more with @EvanTrimboli's code...

Comment: Oooh, I have to set the `<p class="test">...</p>` _before_ I reference the JavaScript file because it's being invoked before it loads `.test`. Well, this creates a new problem... Either way, you solved my question. *accept*